# Can a sequence be uncountably infinite?

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity

The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) for a sequence defines it as such:

> In mathematics, a sequence is an **enumerated** collection of objects in which repetitions are allowed and order matters. [...] The number of elements (**possibly infinite**) is called the length of the sequence. [...] Formally, a sequence can be defined as a function from **natural numbers (the positions of elements in the sequence)** to the elements at each position. [...]

The three parts that I've marked give the impression that cardinality of a sequence as a collection of elements can be infinite but it can only be countably infinite because it is "enumerated" and also it is "defined as a function from natural numbers".

While this makes intuitive sense to me, it is in contrast with the accepted answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326709/possible-to-have-a-continuous-sequence) where it states that any sequence in the form of $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, like $f(n)=n^2$, is "always continuous". This is odd to me because even though the codomain of $f$ is **continuous**, its domain and ultimately its cardinality is **discrete**. This can be demonstrated by writing down the elements of $f$: $1, 4, 9, 16, 25, ...$; one can see that while all element are members of $\mathbb{R}$, they arise from a calculation carried out on members of $\mathbb{N}$ and therefore end up constituting a discrete collection of numbers that is not continuous in any way.

The accepted answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297344/are-sequences-continuous) as well, states that sequences are continuous.

My question is, are sequences continuous or discrete? are they always countable or can they be uncountable?

P.S.: I would like to also ask a more general and seemingly unrelated question: is the continuousness of a function determined by that of its domain or codomain?

Comment: A discrete sequence is a map from $\Bbb N$ (or a set in bijection with $\Bbb N$) to $\Bbb R$ (or whatever), while a continuous sequence would be a map from $\Bbb R$ (or a set in bijection with $\Bbb R$) to $\Bbb R$ (or whatever again). So, a continuous sequence is what you call a function yet.

Comment: It all depends what topologies you select.  It's common enough to just take the discrete topology on the integers (or natural numbers), in which case it would certainly be true that every sequence was continuous (since every subset of the domain is open).  For a more general function, you need information regarding *both* topologies.

Comment: By definition, enumerated means countable.

Comment: What do you mean the codomain is continuous? A function is continuous. There is no meaning for set, like a co-domain,  being continuous, and if You define such a meaning, it won't have any bearing on whether the function is continuous.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Of course there is meaning for the continuousness of a set; for example the interval $[0, 1)$ is a continuous set of real numbers, as is any subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JohnDouma that's what I gathered as well but the two questions I've linked both have accepted answers that say sequences are always continuous [and thus uncountable].

Comment: @SMMH That isn't a definition. $\{1,2\}$ is a subset of the reals, is it really a continuous set? But if you give a definition, it will say nothing about whether a function $\mathbb N\to X$ is continuous, because all such functions are continuous, no matter what topology you give $X.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I didn't say $\{1,2\}$, I said $[0,1)$ which has uncountably infinitely many real numbers in it. Obviously $\{1,2\}$ is finite and countable and discrete, but $[0,1)$ is infinite and uncountable and continuous.

Comment: You said, "[ $(0,1)$ is a continuous set,] as is **any** subset of $\mathbb R.$" $\{1,2\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb R.$  You still haven't  given an actual definition of what you mean by a continuous topological space, $X,$ nor stated what that definition would have to do with whether a function $\mathbb N\to\mathbb X$ is continuous. @SMMH

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142079/discussion-between-smmh-and-thomas-andrews).

Comment: I can't do chat from my iPad, which is my primary usage here, sorry. @SMMH But if you can't produce what the definition is for a "continuous space," maybe you haven't seen such a definition.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews if $S\cap\{(a,b)|b>a\land a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}\neq\emptyset$ then $S$ is continuous

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics) - that's what they call an uncountably infinite "sequence".

Comment: @SMMH: That definition does not really do what you think it does. According to that definition, no subset of $\mathbb R$ is continuous, as $\{(a,b)|b>a\land a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is a set containing all the non-trivial open intervals of $\mathbb R$, whereas $S$ contains elements of $\mathbb R$. It is not possible for $x\in\mathbb R$ to be an interval!

Comment: @SMMH: I think you need to give up on the idea of a set being continuous. It is not a standard mathematical concept. Although can technically define things however you want, it would be terrible to use the word "continuous" to refer to two entirely separate concepts. Usually, when a word is used in two different ways, the two ways are connected: compare "continuous at a point" with "continuous on a set". Or how about the "order of a group" versus the "order of an element of a group"?

Comment: @SMMH: For what it's worth, the closest thing to what you call "a continuous set" is the concept of a [connected space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) in topology. But whether a set $X$ is connected has no bearing on whether a function defined on $X$ is continuous. That's why it would simply be misleading to use the word "continuous" instead of "connected", nevermind that this would be non-standard to begin with.

Comment: The notion of a [transfinite sequence](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22transfinite+sequence%22&filter=0) is fairly well known in many areas of mathematics, and it allows for "linear sequences" having arbitrarily many (cardinality) terms. The reason I said "linear sequences" is because another comment mentioned nets, but nets are probably too much of a generalization for what you're asking about.

Answer (score 6):

Sequences in a set $X$ are functions $\Bbb N\to X$. The image therefore cannot have cardinality greater than that of $\Bbb N$, so sequences are always countable (or finite: the meaning of "countable" can vary). "Discrete cardinality" doesn't mean anything as far as I know.

As functions $\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$ with the usual topology on both sides (discrete, Euclidean) we get that all sequences are continuous *functions* because all functions out of a discrete space are continuous, in the sense of topology. However it's quite common to discuss whether or not a sequence has any *accumulation* or *limit* points, and I think you're confusing ideas around this with "continuity".

It does not mean anything to talk about a "continuous (co)domain". It does make sense to talk about a "discrete (co)domain", but the adjective 'continuous' must be used with great caution. It means one very precise thing that newcomers to topology/analysis often blur with more intuitive notions of 'smoothness'.

Comment: For sequences in $\mathbb R$, notice that for any $\varepsilon>0$ you can take $\delta=1/2$ to get $|f(n)-f(m)|<\varepsilon$ for all $n,m$ with $|n-m|<\delta$. Reason is that this only holds for $n=m$. This is the definition of continuity for metric spaces, in case the [+1] answer is a tad abstract. On the other hand, the generalized statement from the answer is, that all maps $f:U\rightarrow V$ are continuous, if $U$ carries the discrete topology, i.e. all singeltons are open.

Answer (score 5):

In analysis, the term "sequence" usually means a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb R$. Of course, people are free to use the term "sequence" in another way, e.g. to refer to a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb C$ (a "complex-valued sequence"), or a function from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb R$ (a "bi-directional sequence"). It is normally clear from context what definition someone has in mind, or it could be that the precise definition of a sequence does not matter.

However, I suspect that your confusion does not stem from the definition of a sequence. In fact, the terms being misused here are "continuous" and "discrete".

If $f$ is a real-valued function (i.e. its domain and codomain are both subsets of $\mathbb R$), and $a$ is in the domain of $f$, then $f$ is said to be *continuous at $a$* if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that, for all $x$ in the domain of $f$, if $|x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$. If $X$ is a subset of the domain of $f$, then $f$ is said to be *continuous on $X$* if $f$ is continuous at every point of $X$. Simply saying that $f$ is continuous means that $f$ is continuous on its domain.

While it makes sense to speak of a function being continuous, there is no standard definition of a set being continuous. And, as Thomas Andrews mentions in the comments, if we were to define "continuity" for sets, this definition would bear no relation to the definition for functions. However, using the above definition, we can make sense of the term "continuous sequence": it is a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb R$ which is continuous.

A subset $S$ of $\mathbb R$ is *discrete* if for every $x\in S$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap S=\{x\}$, i.e. the only point in $S$ which is less than $\delta$ away from $x$ is $x$ itself. There is no standard definition of the cardinality of a set being discrete: the cardinality of a set is a number, not a subset of $\mathbb R$.

Since $\mathbb N$ is discrete, and every real-valued function with a discrete domain is continuous, it follows that every sequence is continuous. Therefore, we don't usually speak of "continuous sequences", just as we don't usually speak of "triangles with three sides".

Comment: Question: are there actual values for $x$ and $\delta$ such that the definition of continuous holds for sequences, or is it only a vacuous truth? Because I feel like it's vacuous, and that's part of the confusion.

Comment: @NoName: Good question! Strictly speaking, it depends on how continuity is defined. Suppose we use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition. The relevant clause is "if $|x-a|<\delta$ then", which could be modified to "if $\color{red}{0<}|x-a|<\delta$" without chaning the definition of continuity. In both cases, we can use $\delta=1$ to prove that every sequence is continuous. [...]

Comment: [...] However, in the latter case, there is no value of $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $0<|x-a|<1$, so the implication does indeed hold vacuously. In the former case, the implication is technically not vacuous; however, the only value of $x$ in the domain of $f$ satisfying $|x-a|<1$ is $a$ itself, and then it is trivial that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$. If I find the time, I might add to my answer a discussion of how functions with a discrete domain satisfying the definition of continuity in a trivial, if not, vacuous way.